# What is this tag/label on Jacobs coffee lid?

Tags: packaging

I noticed that the Jacobs coffee containers I buy have such tag/label on their lid:

[image]

What is the purpose of this tag? According to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ru&text=coffee&op=translate), the first word means "Coffee", but can't decipher the meaning of the numbers. 250 isn't the weight or amount of coffee, as it's a 200 gram container.

The tag wasn't added by the supermarket from which I buy the coffee.

I didn't notice any other coffee brand with such tag/label on its lid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a [tax stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenue_stamp) used by the Republic of Belarus. The 'РБ' on the right side of the sticker stands for *Republic of Belarus*.

The package is rated for content up to 250 grams. In 2016, [a Belarusian business news website](https://neg.by/novosti/otkrytj/nominal-po-vesu--kontrolnye-znaki-dlya-chaya-i-kofe-differenciruyut/) reported on a duty increase on coffee, it mentions 25 to 250 grams as a category with a fixed duty.

[This website shows similar stickers](https://pandia.ru/text/80/625/38734-4.php) for other products (beer). The bottom two rows of numbers for those sample stickers contain zeros and capital As. It seems to me that those numbers and letters are serial numbers used by the Belarusian tax authorities, perhaps to allow trackability (from a tax perspective, not related to the origin of the coffee).

Comment: Yeah this is most likely it. Waiting a bit to see if others would have more insights. Still, wonder why I don't see it much more, Israel imports all kinds of things from Belarus as far as I can tell, not only the coffee.